# AWS Cognito TOKEN Endpoint giving a 400 Bad Request error "unauthorized_client"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Following the documentation from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html after successfully retrieving an authentication code.

As far as I can tell this is exactly how the request is supposed to be setup:

```
import request from 'request'

function fetchToken(code: any, clientId: string, clientSecret: string) {
  try {
    let tokenEndpoint = `https://example.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token`
    const clientIdEncoded = Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`).toString('base64')

    request.post({
      url:tokenEndpoint,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization':`Basic ${clientIdEncoded}`
      },
      form: {
        code,
        'grant_type':'authorization_code',
        'client_id':clientId,
        'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:3000'
      }},
      function(err,httpResponse,body){
        console.log(httpResponse.statusCode)
        //400
        console.log(httpResponse.statusMessage)
        //Bad Request
        if(err) {
          console.error(err)
        }

        console.log(body)
        //{"error":"unauthorized_client"}
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

Why would be getting `unauthorized_client`? Is there an easier way to debug this?

Edit: tested this in Postman with the same request and getting the same error

**Headers**
[image: Header]
**Body**
[image: Body]

Comment: Please confirm whether `tokenEndpoint = \`https://example.auth...` is your actual code or is a value you sanitized.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, added screenshots from Postman that show the same error. Not sure if that answers your question. Pretty sure both services are encoding form values

Answer (score 3):

Please check if the Cognito User Pool App is using secret key. If you have created with secret key option, that must be included in the `Authorization` header of the request.

Comment: Just wanted to check where is the "secret key" located on cognito?

Comment: The secret key is a check box option you can set when you create the client.